# How do I choose GFI plug end replacement?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Would it be safe to replace a 16Amp GFI plug end (hair dryer) with a 15 Amp GFI plug end?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement StackExchange!  What is the rated power of the device?

Comment: Yes, what's the rated wattage of the hairdryer?

Comment: probably; the wattages on those tend to be exaggerated (like stereos) so that it looks more "powerful" on the shelf than others. Generally consumer appliances in the US are limited to 15A (radiators, lawn mowers, compressors, etc).

Comment: It's constant around here: people who have a GFCI trip (typically on a breaker or outlet) and their instant assumption is *that the GFCI itself has malfunctioned*.  Of course they replace it (often 2-3 times) and sadly realize it was their appliance all along, and that the GFCI was just doing its job.  Hair dryers have a limited service life, I'd hate for you to do all  that work and discover it's the hair dryer not the GFCI.